# Failed to create dataSource in wildfly 28

Tags: mysql, jdbc, wildfly, driver, datasource

I'm trying to add my driver in the wilfdly console 28 all this because I have to create a data source I created all module.xml and modified the standalone.xml file but it keeps giving me this error, I also tried to configure it via deployements in the wildfly console but it's not working and I really don't understand why

This is my module.xml
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjnw0.png)

This is my standalone.xml
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsOkd.png)

This is the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viGz9.png)

This is the one i create in console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxcFh.png)

I created the xml file I modified the standalone xml but nothing, I tried to create it in the deployement section but nothing

Answer (score 0):

Your name doesn't match between your module where you call it just "myself" and the longer name used in your datasource